Pivot with subcategories with grouping Microsoft SQL
enter image description hereI tried to create a SQL query in Microsoft MS by using Pivot that listed people(column1) counts of food and medicine products( so in column 2 should be both types of product for each person) and bought by month ( so next tree columns JAN, Feb, March).
The expected result I am eager to divide the product by 2 types in the "Product" column
At this moment I have this, but this counts only the total number of positions.
 select 
      person, 
  [January], 
  [February], 
  [March] 
from 
  (
    select 
      person, 
      , 
      DATENAME(Month, CreationTime) AS [Month], 
      product 
    from 
      report 
    where 
      producttype = 'food' 
      or product = 'medicine' 
      and year(creationTime) = 2024
  ) as srs pivot (
    count(product) for [Month] in ([January], [February], [March])
  ) as pvt

I will be appreciate if you can help me to reach my expected result ( please look at pic. )

It would be helpful to have the sample input and desired output in the question.  Tables are supported, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support
